# htaccess redirect with bad formated query string

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, query-string

I'm trying to redirect a url with a bad formatted query string generated by joomla.

The url `/index.php?/Some-String/` (notice the absence of a regular parameter `?x=`) to one of the following:

```
/some-string
```

*or*

```
/index.php?q=/Some-String/
```

I tried `Redirect 301 /index.php?/Some-String/ /some-string`
but i get a redirect to `/?%2FSome-String%2F=`

I tried also replacing `?/` with `?q=/` without success.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond {THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?(?:q=|)([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It is not working. It still redirects to `/?%2FSome-String%2F=`

Comment: Something else is doing the redirecting then, maybe something in the php script?

Comment: It is possible you are right about `/?%2FSome-String%2F=` being the result of a redirect in the app. However, i tested your code with an empty folder having just the .htaccess and an empty index.php and now it is not redirected at all. Nothing happens even if I change the target from index.php to test.php.

Comment: The webserver is Apache 2.2.22 with mod_rewrite enabled